# Hidden forms shown when pages load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Hidden form element shown when page load. i tried using this code but that  hides after the pages load too

here is my **html/PHP code**

```
 <div id="i1" class="hidden1" style="position:relative;  overflow:hidden;">
 <?php   
    $record = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT Tread_Design FROM db WHERE Tread_Design='HF3' or Tread_Design='HF4' or Tread_Design='HF2' or Tread_Design='I3' or Tread_Design='HF3' or Tread_Design='HF4' or Tread_Design='HF2' or Tread_Design='I3' or Tread_Design='I1' or Tread_Design='R3'");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)) 
 {
    echo "<input  type='checkbox' name='".$row['Tread_Design']."' value='".$row['Tread_Design']."'>"."&nbsp;"
    .$row['Tread_Design']."&nbsp;";
  }
 ?>
```

Here is the page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
   $('#i1').hide();
   $('#mylist').change(function () {
   if ($('#mylist').val() == "TURF") {
     $('#i1').show();
     $('#i1').show();
     } else {
    $('#i1').hide();
   $('#i1').hide();
   }
});
 });
```

I USE THE CODE BELOW IT HIDES AFTER THE PAGE LOADS TOO

```
div.hidden
{
  display: none
}
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#extraControls").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: in your HTML I can see wrong css class `class="hidden1" `. Please correct it.

Comment: where is `div` with an id `extraControls`? If you are referring to `div` with id `i1` then in your JS code you should do like `$("div#i1").removeClass("hidden");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put the CSS at first in head ... so they will load first 
then the html ... so the browser will not show the hidden forms 
then the JS ... at the footer so it will load last and remove the classes

btw in your CSS to are point to wrong class name . it should be hidden1

```
div.hidden1
{
display: none
}
```

Comment: try also use 
opacity : 0; 
so it will hide the elements and not mess the page .

Comment: please make the answer as accepted so the Question will be resolved ... and easy for other people have same problem to get the answer ..

Comment: ya when i tried to click accept button prompt me to wait for some minutes

Comment: Good to know Thanks a lot J.!

Answer (score 2):

```
//change your css
div#extraControls
{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That was a typo when i post the question. still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You are referring the wrong class name.

The hiding property is set to class `hidden` and you have applied class `hidden1`.

It should be:

```
<div id="i1" class="hidden" style="position:relative;  overflow:hidden;">
<!-- Observe the class name, you have given display:none property to class hidden not hidden1-->
```

Basically, you need to hide some of the elements at page load.

Later they can be shown.

So, use `display:none` property.

This will load elements on page load but hide them.

This is very simple and no javascript/jQuery needed.

Comment: That was a typo when i post the question. still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Your container's using `hidden1` instead of `hidden` as defined in your css. change either the class of the container or the class name in the style.

Comment: i fix that but that makes elements hidden after page loads